# Insert into one database row from different html pages

Tags: php, html, mysql

I only began working with php recently, so maybe this is a simple question. I could not, however, find an answer to it here.

I have a database which I want to fill with content from my html pages. To fill it from one page, works nicely and without trouble.

However, I have different variables that come from different html pages but should be inserted in the same database and in the same row (with same ID).

For example:

Page1

```
<form action="tomydatabase.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="varA" id="varA" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="varB" id="varB" value="">
</form>
```

Page2

```
<form action="tomydatabase.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="varC" id="varC" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="varD" id="varD" value="">
</form>
```

And this is part of my php script:

```
$A = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['varA']);
$B = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['varB']);
$C = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['varC']);
$D = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['varD']);
$sql="INSERT INTO `table02` (`variableA`, `variableB`, `variableC`, `variableD`)
VALUES ('$A', '$B', '$C', '$D');
```

What I want to achieve is that the values of variable A and B from the first html page are put into the same row as variable C and D from the second page. How could I do that?

Comment: Store varA and varB on Session. Or you can add varA, varB as insert and then do update with varC and varD.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Start Session
session_start();

// Get value for $A: from POST (if is set) else from SESSION (if is set) 
if( isset($_POST['varA'])
    $A = $_POST['varA'];
elseif(isset($_SESSION['varA']))
    $A = $_SESSION['varA'];
else
    $A = '';

// Store last value for $A
$_SESSION['varA'] = $A;

// Get value for $B: from POST (if is set) else from SESSION (if is set) 
if( isset($_POST['varB'])
    $B = $_POST['varB'];
elseif(isset($_SESSION['varB']))
    $B = $_SESSION['varB'];
else
    $B = '';

// Store last value for $B
$_SESSION['varB'] = $B;

// Get value for $C and $D
$C = (isset($_POST['varC'])) ? $_POST['varC'] : '';
$D = (isset($_POST['varD'])) ? $_POST['varD'] : '';

// Make query
$sql = sprintf(
    "INSERT INTO `table02` (`variableA`, `variableB`, `variableC`, `variableD`) 
     VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')",
     mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $A),
     mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $B),
     mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $C),
     mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $D)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of Session !

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}

// Get Values
if(isset($_POST['varA']))
    $_SESSION['varA'] = $_POST['varA'];
if(isset($_POST['varB']))
    $_SESSION['varB'] = $_POST['varB'];
if(isset($_POST['varC']))
    $_SESSION['varC'] = $_POST['varC'];
if(isset($_POST['varD']))
    $_SESSION['varD'] = $_POST['varD'];

// If we have got all variables ready
if (
isset($_SESSION['varA']) 
&& isset($_SESSION['varB']) 
&& isset($_SESSION['varC']) 
&& isset($_SESSION['varD'])
)
{
    // Make query
    $sql = sprintf(
        "INSERT INTO `table02` (`variableA`, `variableB`, `variableC`, `variableD`) 
        VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')",
        mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['varA']),
        mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['varB']),
        mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['varC']),
        mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['varD'])
    );
}
```